# Relationship between mass and twist for operators with spin $s$ in the $AdS/CFT$ correspondence

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

The relation between scaling dimension and mass of a corresponding field in AdS is given by: $$\Delta=\frac{d}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{4}+m^2R^2},$$
Is this formula only valid for scalar fields? I would expect this formula gets modified for spin-$s$ operators and fields so that the minimal twist $\tau=d-1$, where $\tau=
\Delta -s$, corresponds to a massless field. Can someone point out the appropriate reference and give a simple explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are mixing notations. For the first formula you give to be correct, $d$ needs to be the boundary dimension. But for $\tau = d - 1$ to be the minimal twist, $d$ needs to be the bulk dimension. I will use boundary from now on.

But anyway, that expectation is almost right. The minimal value of twist instead gets mapped to a strictly negative squared mass called the BF bound. The generalization to non-zero spin is
\begin{equation}
\Delta(\Delta - d) + s(s + d - 2) = m^2 R^2
\end{equation}
which is easy to remember because the left hand side is an eigenvalue of the quadratic Casimir of the conformal group. These [TASI](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04948) notes are my favourite source which makes the relation between the bulk Laplacian and boundary Casimir operator manifest.