# Vectors in AdS/CFT: scaling dimension and near boundary behaviour

Tags: conformal-field-theory, vector-fields, gauge-invariance, ads-cft

I'm trying to understand how the near boundary expansion of a field in AdS$_{d+1}$ is related to the conformal dimension of the corresponding operator in the dual CFT$_d$.
I use coordinates in which the boundary is at $r\to\infty$.

**What I understand: scalar field case**

A scalar field near the AdS boundary behaves as
\begin{equation}
\phi(r\to\infty)\sim \frac{A}{r^{\Delta_+}}+\frac{B}{r^{\Delta_-}}
\end{equation}
where $\Delta_{\pm}=\frac{d}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{4}+m^2L^2}$ are the solutions of
$$
m^2L^2=\Delta(\Delta-d)
$$and $\Delta_+$ is found to be the conformal dimension of the dual operator. Do you agree so far?

**What I do NOT understand: vector field case**

For a vector field we have [ref: [Zaanen's book pag 16](http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/%7Ealberto/apuntes/zaanen.pdf)]
$$
\Delta^{vec}_\pm=\frac{d}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{(d-2)^2}{4}+m^2L^2},
$$
solutions of $m^2L^2=(\Delta^{vec}-1)(\Delta^{vec}-(d-1))$. Now, since there are again two solutions to the algebraic equation above, I would expect the vector field near the boundary to behave like
$$
A_\mu(r\to\infty)\sim \frac{a_\mu}{r^{\Delta^{vec}_+}}+\frac{b_\mu}{r^{\Delta^{vec}_-}}
$$
Why does this not happen?
How are the two solutions $\Delta^{vec}_\pm$ related to the conformal dimension of the boundary vector operator?

**Example**

As an example, I propose you a massless vector field. In this case the two solutions of the algebraic equation are
$$
\Delta^{vec}_+=d-1\;\;\;\;, \;\;\;    \Delta^{vec}_-=1
$$
and so I would expect the vector field to behave as something like $$A_\mu\sim\frac{a_\mu}{r^{d-1}}+\frac{b_\mu}{r^{1}}$$
However, for an AdS-RN black hole the $A_t$ field [is](http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/%7Ealberto/apuntes/zaanen.pdf)
$$
A_t=\mu\left(1-\frac{r_h^{d-2}}{r^{d-2}}\right)\:.
$$

Can someone explain this? Can this be related to gauge symmetry?
Of course, there is no reason why my expectation should be satisfied, but then I don't understand the point of calling out the two solutions $\Delta^{vec}_\pm$.

$\small{\text{Notice: in the reference I cited, they use $d+1$ instead of $d$, because they work with AdS}_{d+2}\text{ and CFT}_{d+1}.}$

Answer (score 0):

The gauge field of the AdS-RN solution doesn't satisfy $\partial^2 A_\mu = 0$ in a pure AdS background right? That's the equation you should be solving in order to verify that a vector field falls off as $1 / r^{\Delta^{vec}_\pm}$. Given the mass, the [Casimir equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/725765/relationship-between-mass-and-twist-for-operators-with-spin-s-in-the-ads-cft/725827) allows you to compute two solutions for the scaling dimension. But this is defined as the power of $x^2$ that appears in $\left < 0 | A_\mu(x) A_\nu(0) | 0 \right >$. Not the two-point function in a state created by a heavy operator that's dual to a black hole.